# HAProxy cannot bind socket 80 or 443 - Ubuntu

Tags: sockets, port, load-balancing, haproxy

Just to preface this question - I have attempted all other solutions I found via search on here. All of those were suggesting to check if other services are bound to the ports but in my case there isn't. Others were discussing SELinux which is irrelevant here as I'm running Ubuntu

I'm trying to set up HAProxy to load balance 3 nodejs webservers following this example: https://serversforhackers.com/c/load-balancing-with-haproxy

Here's my haproxy.conf file:

```
global
    log /dev/log    local0
    log /dev/log    local1 notice
    chroot /var/lib/haproxy
    stats timeout 30s
    user haproxy
    group haproxy
    daemon
    tune.ssl.default-dh-param 20148
    # Default SSL material locations
    ca-base /etc/ssl/certs
    crt-base /etc/ssl/private

    # See: https://ssl-config.mozilla.org/#server=haproxy&server-version=2.0.3&config=intermediate
        ssl-default-bind-ciphers ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
        ssl-default-bind-ciphersuites TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256:TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384:TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256
        ssl-default-bind-options ssl-min-ver TLSv1.2 no-tls-tickets

defaults
    log global
    mode    http
    option  httplog
    option  dontlognull
        timeout connect 5000
        timeout client  50000
        timeout server  50000
    errorfile 400 /etc/haproxy/errors/400.http
    errorfile 403 /etc/haproxy/errors/403.http
    errorfile 408 /etc/haproxy/errors/408.http
    errorfile 500 /etc/haproxy/errors/500.http
    errorfile 502 /etc/haproxy/errors/502.http
    errorfile 503 /etc/haproxy/errors/503.http
    errorfile 504 /etc/haproxy/errors/504.http
    
frontend localnodes
    bind *:80
    bind *:443 ssl crt ~/cert.pem
    mode http
    default_backend nodes
    
backend nodes
    mode http
    balance roundrobin
    option forwardfor
    http-request set-header X-Forwarded-Port %[dst_port]
    http-request add-header X-Forwarded-Proto https if { ssl_fc }
    option httpchk HEAD / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost:localhost
    server web01 127.0.0.1:9000 check
    server web02 127.0.0.1:9001 check
    server web03 127.0.0.1:9002 check
```

And when I run haproxy -f /etc/haproxy/haproxy.conf -db I get this error:

```
[ALERT] 295/105753 (3029) : Starting frontend localnodes: cannot bind socket [0.0.0.0:80]
[ALERT] 295/105753 (3029) : Starting frontend localnodes: cannot bind socket [0.0.0.0:443]
```

When I run netstat -anp | grep ":80" nothing is returned so nothing else is using the port.

Comment: asking after years, you had any luck resolving this?

Answer (score 0):

Can try this

`setsebool -P haproxy_connect_any=1`

Comment: I tried this, this is specific to SELinux though and isn't installed (or compatible with I think) on Ubuntu.

Comment: Try to kill if any service is running on that port you are trying to use and then restart haproxy

Comment: is it run as root?

Comment: No other services running on the port - also running as root